# Enable reading of .cvs data table as a separated columns and rows data

Tags: r, database, csv

I have this dataset

```
> dput(head(Filter, 50))
structure(list(X..Subject...Change...Ndist...correct_response...test_response...correct...response_time...Block...Attention_focus...Awareness_attention...trial...Age...Online_hrs...Sex...MM_hrs...MM_TV...MM_IM...MM_SM...MMI...MMH...MMS...MMI_grp...MMS_grp...MMH_grp...MPI...screen_width...screen_height...backend...location. = c("1,1,\"yes\",6,\"left\",\"right\",0,976,1,1,3,1,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"2,1,\"yes\",6,\"left\",\"left\",1,807,1,1,3,2,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"3,1,\"yes\",2,\"left\",\"left\",1,622,1,1,3,3,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"4,1,\"no\",2,\"right\",\"right\",1,710,1,1,3,4,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"5,1,\"no\",4,\"right\",\"right\",1,598,1,1,3,5,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"6,1,\"yes\",0,\"left\",\"left\",1,574,1,1,3,6,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"7,1,\"no\",6,\"right\",\"right\",1,791,1,1,3,7,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"8,1,\"no\",4,\"right\",\"right\",1,622,1,1,3,8,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"9,1,\"yes\",4,\"left\",\"left\",1,766,1,1,3,9,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"10,1,\"yes\",0,\"left\",\"left\",1,668,1,1,3,10,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"11,1,\"no\",2,\"right\",\"left\",0,1246,1,1,3,11,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"12,1,\"yes\",4,\"left\",\"left\",1,992,1,1,3,12,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"13,1,\"no\",0,\"right\",\"right\",1,797,1,1,3,13,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"14,1,\"no\",0,\"right\",\"right\",1,878,1,1,3,14,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"15,1,\"yes\",2,\"left\",\"left\",1,1191,1,1,3,15,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"16,1,\"no\",6,\"right\",\"right\",1,990,1,1,3,16,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"17,1,\"yes\",0,\"left\",\"left\",1,1666,2,3,1,1,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"18,1,\"no\",6,\"right\",\"right\",1,789,2,3,1,2,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"19,1,\"yes\",6,\"left\",\"left\",1,758,2,3,1,3,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"20,1,\"yes\",2,\"left\",\"left\",1,654,2,3,1,4,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"21,1,\"no\",4,\"right\",\"right\",1,726,2,3,1,5,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"22,1,\"yes\",6,\"left\",\"left\",1,1408,2,3,1,6,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"23,1,\"yes\",4,\"left\",\"left\",1,718,2,3,1,7,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"24,1,\"yes\",4,\"left\",\"left\",1,766,2,3,1,8,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"25,1,\"no\",2,\"right\",\"right\",1,750,2,3,1,9,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"26,1,\"no\",0,\"right\",\"right\",1,649,2,3,1,10,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"27,1,\"no\",0,\"right\",\"right\",1,656,2,3,1,11,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"28,1,\"no\",6,\"right\",\"right\",1,1418,2,3,1,12,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"29,1,\"yes\",2,\"left\",\"left\",1,671,2,3,1,13,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"30,1,\"no\",2,\"right\",\"left\",0,809,2,3,1,14,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"31,1,\"yes\",0,\"left\",\"left\",1,767,2,3,1,15,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"32,1,\"no\",4,\"right\",\"right\",1,649,2,3,1,16,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"33,1,\"yes\",4,\"left\",\"left\",1,1038,3,2,5,1,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"34,1,\"no\",6,\"right\",\"right\",1,820,3,2,5,2,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"35,1,\"yes\",2,\"left\",\"left\",1,654,3,2,5,3,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"36,1,\"no\",0,\"right\",\"right\",1,756,3,2,5,4,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"37,1,\"no\",0,\"right\",\"right\",1,1087,3,2,5,5,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"38,1,\"yes\",2,\"left\",\"left\",1,773,3,2,5,6,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"39,1,\"no\",2,\"right\",\"right\",1,702,3,2,5,7,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"40,1,\"yes\",0,\"left\",\"left\",1,926,3,2,5,8,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"41,1,\"no\",4,\"right\",\"right\",1,838,3,2,5,9,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"42,1,\"yes\",6,\"left\",\"right\",0,1702,3,2,5,10,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"43,1,\"yes\",4,\"left\",\"left\",1,822,3,2,5,11,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"44,1,\"yes\",6,\"left\",\"right\",0,1030,3,2,5,12,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"45,1,\"no\",6,\"right\",\"right\",1,518,3,2,5,13,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"46,1,\"yes\",0,\"left\",\"left\",1,599,3,2,5,14,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"47,1,\"no\",4,\"right\",\"right\",1,925,3,2,5,15,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"48,1,\"no\",2,\"right\",\"right\",1,629,3,2,5,16,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"49,1,\"no\",2,\"right\",\"right\",1,1077,4,1,3,1,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\"", 
"50,1,\"yes\",2,\"left\",\"left\",1,917,4,1,3,2,24,2,0,3.5,1.666666667,2,1.666666667,0.711428571,2.49,1.777777778,\"LMM\",\"LMM\",\"LMM\",51,1024,768,\"xpyriment\",\"lab\""
)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

that as you could see is a .csv format. By the way, despite I looked for reading it as separated columns and rows element I am not able to find a code to enable this kind of reading option. Could anyone know how to enable it?

If interested, this the original source I found the file in

https://mfr.osf.io/render?url=https://osf.io/j79ne/?direct%26mode=render%26action=download%26mode=render

After running the code `Filter <- read.csv("filter_raw.csv", sep = ',')` I obtain a dataset like this

[image]

On which it is not possible to carry out the whole code that researchers have uploaded here https://osf.io/nkdw5/

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure what do you mean with "as separated columns and row data". Can you share an little example of what output you are getting and what output do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, that is a .csv doc. Comma should be the separator, but since I've tried quite hard to get it with separated-cell variable , I've post the question here. It should be reshaped normally with each value in a different cell.

Comment: Did you try read.csv? if so, did it work? The linked data seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I've tried but it didn't work to me. Can you post down the code you've used?

Comment: Once downloaded as "filter_raw.csv", `read.csv("filter_raw.csv")`. If that's not working, please add the results you are getting to the question, so there's a better chance to find an answer that works for you.

Comment: More details added

Comment: Even the` Filter <- read.table("filter_raw.csv", sep = ",", header=T)` does not work

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue. Have you tried using the function `read_csv` from the readr package or the function `fread` from the data.table package?

Comment: `fread` could be a solution but actually I am not able to use that. I have used the `read_csv` function but it doees not work. Just for curiosity...How many rows and columns have your dataset after uploading it

Comment: I've tried updating the link where to find the dataset in. If you can please suggest any further solution (for example how to set up better the parameteres for `fread` function) it would be great

Comment: Since I can't replicate your problem, a patchwork solution is using `separate`, from the tidyr package, to split your one column into many using "," as a separator. If this still doesn't work, then there's definitely an issue not accounted for by code alone (regional settings for example), and that goes beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Im not sure if you or I are using the wrong link but `pth = "https://osf.io/j79ne/download"; dat = read.csv(pth)` downloads a csv fine (I got the link from going to https://osf.io/nkdw5/, then clicking on filter_raw.csv in the Data section, and then copying the link from the download button (upper right of page))

Comment: Thanks. This is the right answer I was looking for.

Comment: If you would like to give your contribute and have some expertise in building table, I have published also a new question in this regards here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70059022/reproduce-a-complex-table-with-double-headesrs. Feel free to leave your comment, if you would like

Comment: @mały_statystyczny; good stuff; please write up an answer if you have it working

Comment: Should I write up the answer that it worked for me here below? By myself?

Comment: May I ask to report the answer here below.... it's better that since you were the one that has suggested, you should be the one worth of upvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this will be much more convenient with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

for more information on pandas refer:- https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/default.asp

Answer (score 2):

The wrong link was used in the question. The correct link can be found by going to https://osf.io/nkdw5/, then clicking on `filter_raw.csv` in the `Data` section, and then copying the link from the download button (upper right of page).

Here the solution that has worked better.

```
pth <- "https://osf.io/j79ne/download"
dat <- read.csv(pth)
```

Comment: I think that you should keep this marked as the solution; the other answer is for python not R and doesn't details how to get the link from the webpage, which was the difficuly.