# Reproduce a complex table with double headesrs

Tags: r, dplyr, flextable, gtsummary

I would like to create the following table

[image]

Where

```
Alzheimer’s Disease Assessment Scale-Cognitive  = ADAS_CogT0
Rey-Osterrieth Complex Figure Test immediate recall = ROCF_IT0
Copy of Rey-Osterrieth Complex Figure test   = ROCF_CT0
Rey-Osterrieth Complex Figure Test delayed recall   = ROCf_RT0
Phonemic verbal fluency = PVF_T0
Semantic verbal fluency = SVF_T0
```

I have started manipulating data as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(rms)
library(lme4)
library(flextable)
library(gtsummary)
library(data.table)
library(plotrix)
library(purrr)

out <db %>% 
  mutate(GROUP = fct_recode(GROUP, CONTROL = "CONTROLLO")) %>%
  to_long(keys  = c("tests0", "tests7"),
          values =c("score0", "score7"),
          grep("T0$", names(.), value = TRUE), 
          grep("T7$", names(.), value = TRUE)) %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  mutate(Gender = factor(Gender, levels = c(1, 0), labels = c("M", "F")),
         across(c(tests0, tests7), factor))
  
out1 <- out %>%   
  group_by(tests0, GROUP) %>%
  filter(GROUP == 'TRAINING') %>% 
  summarise(mean0 = mean(score0, na.rm = T),
            stderr0 = std.error(score0, na.rm = T), 
            mean7 = mean(score7, na.rm = T), 
            stederr7 = std.error(score7, na.rm = T),
            diff.std.mean = t.test(score0, score7, paired = T)$estimate, 
            p.value = t.test(score0, score7, paired = T)$p.value  
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

out2 <-  out %>% 
  group_by(tests0, GROUP) %>% 
  filter(GROUP == 'CONTROL') %>% 
  summarise(mean0 = mean(score0, na.rm = T),
            stderr0 = std.error(score0, na.rm = T), 
            mean7 = mean(score7, na.rm = T), 
            stederr7 = std.error(score7, na.rm = T),
            diff.std.mean = t.test(score0, score7, paired = T)$estimate, 
            p.value = t.test(score0, score7, paired = T)$p.value  
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
  
out3 <- out1 %>%
  bind_cols(out2) %>% 
  select(., -'tests0...9') %>%
  flextable()
```

obtaing this results

[image]

I got stuck at this point, where I am a bit confuse as to create the final column for the between-group differences that are supposed to contain

mean difference of the of the two MEAN DIFFERENCE COLUMNS you can see in the blank picture  and I don't how to enter it into the code. Moreover I am not able create the two headers referred to:

```
TRAINING and CONTROL groups 

WITHIN AND BETWEEN GROUPS
```

here the dataset

```
dput(head(db, 100))
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100), GROUP = c("TRAINING", "TRAINING", 
"TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", 
"TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", 
"TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", 
"TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", 
"TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", 
"TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", 
"TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", 
"TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", 
"TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "TRAINING", "CONTROLLO", 
"CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", 
"CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", 
"CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", 
"CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", 
"CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", 
"CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", 
"CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", 
"CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", 
"CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO", "CONTROLLO"), Gender = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), Age = c(74, 76, 
81, 74, 69, 72, 75, 83, 78, 72, 82, 68, 72, 72, 73, 80, 69, 72, 
70, 80, 75, 80, 78, 74, 82, 74, 80, 82, 78, 81, 66, 71, 70, 79, 
78, 73, 72, 77, 77, 71, 83, 74, 70, 71, 77, 69, 67, 64, 79, 71, 
77, 77, 73, 67, 68, 79, 81, 67, 84, 75, 80, 73, 68, 74, 77, 79, 
79, 72, 73, 78, 76, 78, 77, 74, 78, 77, 77, 82, 77, 70, 77, 81, 
79, 75, 74, 78, 69, 77, 73, 77, 70, 79, 70, 72, 77, 72, 71, 71, 
73, 81), Education = c(18, 4, 8, 5, 8, 11, 5, 5, 4, 8, 8, 12, 
5, 18, 13, 5, 13, 13, 5, 5, 13, 5, 3, 8, 17, 5, 8, 5, 5, 8, 17, 
8, 18, 18, 13, 13, 13, 13, 15, 17, 8, 5, 5, 13, 8, 5, 11, 13, 
8, 8, 8, 5, 13, 8, 5, 17, 8, 12, 13, 5, 8, 8, 8, 5, 3, 8, 18, 
5, 8, 13, 8, 5, 17, 8, 5, 17, 5, 8, 11, 8, 8, 5, 12, 3, 8, 8, 
8, 13, 5, 5, 8, 8, 13, 5, 5, 8, 13, 5, 8, 12), ADAS_CogT0 = c(14.66, 
15.33, 17.33, 19, 7.66, 12.6, 18.67, 14.99, 17.99, 17.33, 13.66, 
16.99, 10.66, 9.66, 14.99, 15.66, 13.33, 4.33, 14.33, 15.99, 
16.33, 10.66, 14.66, 10.66, 19.33, 17.66, 15.99, 20.66, 20.6, 
17, 10.33, 6.33, 6.66, 19.99, 13.33, 24.33, 12.33, 10.33, 12.33, 
9.66, 10.99, 13.99, 23, 6.32, 11.32, 13.99, 14.66, 8.99, 14.33, 
9.99, 7.33, 15.66, 14, 7.99, 23.32, 14.66, 9.99, 5.66, 6.99, 
11.66, 10.33, 6.99, 19.32, NA, 10, 17.66, 13.66, 10.32, NA, NA, 
8.66, 9, 6.99, 14.99, 9.66, 13.66, 15.32, 12, 14, 13.66, 11.99, 
15.66, 16, 15, 16.99, 20, 11, 7.99, 8.33, 8.32, 14.99, 18.66, 
10.33, 11.99, 9.32, 17, 14.33, 14.66, 16.6, 9.99), ROCF_CT0 = c(32, 
13.5, 34.7, 26.1, 35.4, 24.6, 28.9, 34.1, 12.1, 28.1, 22.7, 31.6, 
30.4, 34.4, 37.2, 38.1, 18.6, 26.2, 34.8, 37.1, 26.2, 35.1, 37.1, 
36, 11.2, 17.4, 32.7, 28.4, 21.1, 26.7, 31.9, 33.4, 27.4, 32.7, 
33.9, 37.2, 28.2, 34.2, 29.7, 30, 16.2, 37.4, 34.8, 36.6, 33, 
30.8, 34.6, 35.1, 29.7, 36.8, 28, 34.4, 33.7, 28.9, 31.8, 31.7, 
10.2, 27.1, 36.8, 22.4, 35.7, 28, 30.9, 35.4, 26.9, 29.7, 26.7, 
28.8, 32, 37.9, 27, 18.6, 33, 38, 25.1, 31, 27.1, 26.7, 37, 30.4, 
37, 30.1, 36.9, 24.4, 34, 6.7, 20.4, 30.2, 31.1, 33.4, 17.4, 
23.7, 30.6, 28.3, 19.4, 33.4, 31.6, 39.8, 27, 33.9), ROCF_IT0 = c(3.7, 
7.6, 14.9, 13.6, 23.4, 4, 8.1, 23.9, 10.1, 7, 10, 9.2, 15.6, 
10.8, 6.6, 13.6, 4, 15.3, 7.4, 0, 8.6, 22.9, 11.6, 10.1, 6.8, 
12.1, 12.9, 0, 10.6, 5.9, 14.8, 10.9, 10.6, 10.6, 7.5, 7.3, 4.1, 
3.1, 7.6, 13.4, 10.9, 19, 3.4, 11.7, 14.6, 9.4, 16.7, 15.7, 14.5, 
12.5, 15.1, 22.6, 9.1, 15.5, 11, 6.1, 11.5, 5.6, 17.2, 18.1, 
23.5, 15.6, 7.7, 13.5, 14.5, 11.9, 10.3, 11.5, 12.6, 19, 11.9, 
15.4, 17.7, 8.4, 13.4, 5.2, 11.1, 16, 10.9, 8, 22.6, 13.6, 12.2, 
6.5, 13.4, 11.5, 8, 18.1, 10, 11, 5.9, 14.9, 12, 11.4, 17, 5.9, 
15, 10.9, 8.9, 15.7), ROCF_RT0 = c(3.9, 7.8, 16.3, 13.4, 24.1, 
4.7, 7.8, 20.9, 9.8, 5.1, 9.8, 8.2, 16.3, 11.3, 5.9, 14.8, 4.7, 
14.4, 6.7, 0, 4.9, 23.3, 14.8, 11.7, 6.4, 10.3, 14.3, 0, 10.8, 
6.3, 15.4, 10.1, 5.3, 12, 6.9, 5.4, 4.4, 4.4, 7, 10.9, 11.9, 
17.3, 3.7, 12.2, 6.7, 14.7, 16.2, 7.8, 10.8, 10.2, 16.7, 22.8, 
9.1, 15.7, 10.7, 4, 8.8, 6.8, 14.6, 14.5, 24.8, 13.7, 0, 10.3, 
17.3, 11.3, 8, 13.2, 15.2, 18.4, 4.3, 12.8, 18.9, 4.3, 11.8, 
4.9, 11.8, 13.3, 10.3, 7.1, 23.7, 15.8, 16.4, 6.8, 20.3, 11.3, 
7.6, 19.9, 10.8, 12.5, 5.6, 11.3, 11.7, 13.5, 12.3, 5.1, 14.2, 
8.7, 12.3, 16.4), PVF_T0 = c(41.3, 35.4, 16.7, 28.4, 46.9, 33.6, 
39.4, 27.4, 17.4, 37.9, 31.7, 37.6, 33.4, 21.5, 49.5, 40.4, 10.6, 
40.5, 30.6, 28.4, 29.5, 22.4, 45.4, 29.7, 17.3, 39.4, 31.7, 24.4, 
38.4, 22.7, 6.8, 19.9, 56.5, 35.3, 43.5, 32.5, 28.5, 38.5, 22.3, 
32.3, 30.7, 23.4, 18.6, 46.6, 36.7, 35.6, 38.6, 16.9, 38.7, 37.6, 
39.7, 34.4, 27.5, 16.2, 32.6, 48.3, 26.7, 49.9, 40.5, 34.4, 37.7, 
39.7, 23.2, 19.4, 21.4, 33.7, 11.3, 41.6, 23.7, 31.5, 28.7, 34.4, 
33.3, 27.7, 23.4, 32.3, 49.4, 35.7, 26.7, 31.9, 37.7, 35.4, 20.5, 
28.4, 14.7, 30.7, 35.9, 16.5, 27.4, 49.4, 37.9, 27.7, 41.6, 31.6, 
55.4, 42.9, 21.6, 25.6, 26.7, 43.5), SVF_T0 = c(40, 37, 30, 28, 
49, 27, 34, 35, 29, 33, 20, 18, 36, 47, 43, 39, 36, 38, 48, 31, 
25, 34, 31, 33, 24, 30, 45, 20, 33, 34, 29, 42, 40, 37, 37, 25, 
28, 42, 19, 32, 37, 35, 20, 43, 33, 40, 40, 42, 27, 35, 29, 39, 
31, 48, 41, 27, 32, 45, 39, 40, 36, 38, 27, 32, 47, 36, 24, 40, 
38, 29, 43, 47, 38, 33, 44, 39, 46, 36, 32, 38, 38, 35, 26, 43, 
29, 24, 33, 30, 33, 57, 40, 37, 44, 34, 46, 41, 33, 35, 29, 37
), ADAS_CogT7 = c(16, 9.32, 21.33, 17, 8.32, 11, 14.99, 10.99, 
17, 18.33, 13.32, 14.34, 8.99, 7, 11.99, 15.33, 6.99, 5.33, 12.32, 
13, 21.32, 7.99, 13.33, 11.99, 17.32, 16.32, 16.33, 14.66, 18.99, 
17.33, 7.99, 9.33, 10.99, NA, 12.99, 16.33, 21.66, 9, 9.34, 8.66, 
8.33, 13.66, 15.66, 6.66, 10.99, 13.33, 13.33, 7.99, 11.99, 11.32, 
7.33, 9.66, 6.99, NA, 15.99, 15.66, 14.66, 6.32, 7, 11, 14, 10.33, 
24.66, NA, 14.99, NA, 15.99, 9.32, NA, NA, 9.99, 9.33, 7.66, 
17.33, 10.32, 16, 17, 12.99, 15, 14.33, 10, 14.99, 19, 13.99, 
19.33, NA, 10, 6.99, 11.66, 6.66, 14.33, 16, 8.66, 10, NA, 20, 
14.99, 19.66, 26.66, 8.99), ROCF_CT7 = c(33, 23.9, 28.7, 39.1, 
36.4, 29.2, 11.4, 38.1, 18.1, 28.4, 22.2, 18.6, 37, 35, 33.2, 
23.6, 21.1, 30.2, 28.8, 37.1, 32.2, 33.1, 26.1, 38, 23.6, 21.4, 
37.3, 36.4, 15.1, 35.7, 29.9, 31.4, 32.4, NA, 37.9, 28.2, 37.2, 
31.9, 36.7, 24.5, 19.2, 23.4, 32.8, 36.2, 31.7, 24.3, 31.6, 33.1, 
19.2, 30.4, 32.7, 24.4, 36.2, NA, 28.1, 31.7, 19.7, 31.6, 28.3, 
27.4, 37.7, 35, 33.4, 34.4, 32.1, NA, 33.7, 31.8, NA, 34.9, 15, 
20.1, 31, 35, 37.1, 29, 32.6, 31.7, 28.4, 34.4, 35.7, 35.1, 35.9, 
27.4, 34, NA, 17.4, 28.9, 35.4, 33.4, 30.4, 14.7, 33.2, 26.8, 
NA, 20, 33.6, 26.8, 36, 34.9), ROCF_IT7 = c(1.7, 12.1, 5.9, 12.1, 
24.4, 9.8, 7.6, 24.4, 9.6, 7, 11.5, 9.7, 17.1, 14.2, 4.6, 12.1, 
4.5, 18.8, 8.4, 14.6, 6.1, 17.1, 15.1, 13.1, 11.8, 12.1, 15.9, 
7.6, 11.1, 5.9, 23.8, 12.4, 11.1, NA, 11, 7.8, 5.6, 6.5, 10.1, 
9.9, 14.4, 17, 6.4, 27.3, 16, 14.4, 19.7, 16.2, 8.5, 8, 20.5, 
15.1, 15.6, NA, 9, 8.6, 8.5, 13.2, 17.7, 14.1, 11, 9.1, 7, 16, 
20.4, NA, 12.3, 16, NA, 15, 8.4, 17.9, 19.7, 11.9, 18.6, 4.7, 
12.1, 17.5, 9, 5.5, 17.4, 12.1, 9.7, 9.5, 13.4, NA, 7.5, 14.5, 
11, 19.5, 4.9, 11.9, 26, 12, NA, 3.9, 5.5, 6.4, 4.9, 16.2), ROCF_RT7 = c(2.4, 
9.3, 6.3, 12.4, 22.6, 8.9, 7.8, 21.9, 9.8, 5.1, 10.8, 4.2, 12.3, 
18.9, 2.9, 13.8, 1.2, 19.9, 4.2, 9.8, 5.9, 21.3, 12.3, 10.2, 
12.1, 7.8, 6.3, 7.8, 9.8, 6.3, 16.9, 11.6, 11.3, NA, 8.9, 16.9, 
3.9, 6.4, 13, 9.9, 14.9, 18.4, 3.7, 15.4, 8.8, 14.2, 14.7, 14.3, 
8.8, 5.1, 21.8, 14.3, 11.4, NA, 8.7, 9.5, 8.8, 14.2, 17, 13.8, 
12.8, 9.7, 5.1, 15.3, 22.8, NA, 6.4, 12.7, NA, 20.9, 7.8, 11.8, 
22.4, 4.3, 17.8, 4.9, 13.8, 16.4, 7.4, 5.6, 24.8, 11.8, 9.4, 
11.8, 20.3, NA, 7.1, 13.9, 12.3, 23.5, 2.6, 14.8, 15.2, 11.7, 
NA, 4.3, 6.7, 5.2, 7.3, 18.4), PVF_T7 = c(38.3, 49.4, 16.7, 31.4, 
60.9, 29.5, 48.4, 28.4, 17.4, 32.9, 40.7, 42.6, 42.4, 32.3, 38.5, 
40.4, 20.4, 40.5, 42.6, 28.4, 27.5, 24.4, 40.4, 28.7, 5.3, 38.4, 
46.7, 26.4, 37.4, 23.7, 9.8, 34.9, 55.5, NA, 38.5, 38.5, 25.5, 
43.5, 36.3, 30.3, 32.7, 15.4, 21.6, 40.5, 38.7, 48.6, 47.6, 26.9, 
35.7, 31.9, 47.7, 35.4, 29.5, NA, 33.6, 48.3, 27.7, 55.6, 39.5, 
30.4, 36.7, 38.7, 23.9, 26.4, 28.4, NA, 18.3, 47.6, NA, 35.5, 
29.7, 39.4, 44.3, 26.7, 29.4, 31.3, 44.4, 30.7, 11.5, 40.9, 37.7, 
40.4, 14.5, 21.4, 14.7, NA, 29.9, 20.5, 34.4, 55.4, 32.9, 20.7, 
27.6, 31.6, NA, 7.7, 25.6, 22.6, 22.7, 34.5), SVF_T7 = c(26, 
48, 30, 29, 43, 25, 42, 36, 31, 27, 22, 21, 40, 46, 32, 29, 32, 
38, 46, 31, 20, 36, 35, 32, 12, 28, 47, 20, 33, 30, 22, 44, 35, 
NA, 36, 21, 24, 45, 25, 25, 30, 27, 34, 50, 31, 42, 34, 40, 25, 
31, 41, 37, 38, NA, 38, 19, 29, 46, 40, 38, 36, 34, 31, 40, 39, 
NA, 19, 40, NA, 29, 44, 43, 43, 31, 45, 28, 35, 31, 33, 36, 28, 
35, 34, 34, 29, NA, 26, 30, 34, 57, 40, 36, 41, 36, NA, 22, 31, 
29, 26, 31)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not reproduce your code as some datasets are missing.

Below an example with various method to add header rows.

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
by <- c("species", "island")

tabl <- palmerpenguins::penguins %>% 
  group_by(across(all_of(by))) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(ends_with("mm"),
           list(
             mean = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
             median = ~ median(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
             sd = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)
           )
           ),
    .groups = "drop"
  )

tab_header <- tibble( key = colnames(tabl)) %>% 
  separate(col = key, into = c("part", "measure", "unit", "stat"), 
           fill = "right", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  select(-unit) %>% 
  mutate(
    measure = if_else(is.na(measure), part, measure),
    stat = if_else(is.na(stat), measure, stat)
  )
tab_header

flextable(tabl) %>% 
  flextable::set_header_df(tab_header, key = "key") %>% 
  merge_h(part = "header") %>% 
  merge_at(part = "header", i = 1:3, j = 1) %>%
  merge_at(part = "header", i = 1:3, j = 2) %>%
  theme_box() %>%
  add_header_row(values = c("", "bada", "boum"), colwidths = c(1, 5, 5)) %>%
  add_header_lines(c("another way to add a row of text")) %>% 
  align(part = "header", i = seq_len(nrow_part(., part = "header")-1), align = "center")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I could try studying better it. Could you please say which was the error you've met with the dataset?

Comment: Not really an error, You added one dataset named `db` and then refering to `t0` and `t7`. Code from db to t1 and t7 is probably missing. Also package sjmisc should be loaded, but I was able to solve that.

Comment: You're right. As far as the problem for t0 and t7, that was due to the fact that the data were allocated onto two spreadsheets and that have been merged with `left_join` function. I've got that error fixed now. If you would to attemp now with the code adjusted, feel free to do it.

Comment: I don't know wether you had chance to look back at the updates. I'm texting because the code you've sugested it's nice, but there some manipulations to do that I'm not able to cope with by myself. Thanks