# How to rewrite the same code with across function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, across

I scripted the following code

```
out %>% group_by(tests0, GROUP) %>% 
  summarise(
            mean0 = mean(score0, na.rm = T),
            stderr0 = std.error(score0, na.rm = T), 
            mean7 = mean(score7, na.rm = T), 
            stederr7 = std.error(score7, na.rm = T),
            diff.std.mean = t.test(score0, score7, paired = T)$estimate, 
            p.value = t.test(score0, score7, paired = T)$p.value, 
            )
```

and I have obtained the following output

```
 tests0     GROUP    mean0 stderr0 mean7 stederr7 diff.std.mean p.value
   <fct>      <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 ADAS_CogT0 CONTROL   12.6   0.525  13.6    0.662        -1.15  0.00182
 2 ADAS_CogT0 TRAINING  14.0   0.613  12.6    0.570         1.40  0.00295
 3 PVF_T0     CONTROL   32.1   1.22   31.3    1.45          0.498 0.636  
 4 PVF_T0     TRAINING  31.6   1.37   34.3    1.51         -2.48  0.0102 
 5 ROCF_CT0   CONTROL   29.6   0.893  30.3    0.821        -0.180 0.835  
 6 ROCF_CT0   TRAINING  30.1   0.906  29.5    0.929         0.489 0.615  
 7 ROCF_IT0   CONTROL   12.8   0.563  12.2    0.683         0.580 0.356  
 8 ROCF_IT0   TRAINING  10.9   0.735  12.3    0.768        -1.44  0.0238 
 9 ROCF_RT0   CONTROL   12.1   0.725  12.5    0.797        -0.370 0.598  
10 ROCF_RT0   TRAINING  10.5   0.746  10.9    0.742        -0.534 0.370  
11 SVF_T0     CONTROL   35.5   1.05   34      1.15          1.42  0.107  
12 SVF_T0     TRAINING  34.1   1.04   32.9    1.16          0.962 0.231
```

In case I would like to do the same via `across function`, What am i supposed to do to achieve the same results, shown into the code above? Actaully I am in trouble becase I was drawing some example from the answer published under this question  [Reproduce a complex table with double headesrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70059022/reproduce-a-complex-table-with-double-headesrs), but I was not able to suit it properly.

Here the dataset

Below you could find the way I would like to obtain the same. It ius a method requiring for .x manipulation.

```
out %>%    
group_by(across(all_of(tests0, GROUP))) %>%    summarise(across(starts_with('score'),                         
list(mean = ~ mean(.x,na.rm = T),            
stderr = ~ std.error(.x, na.rm = TRUE),            
diff.std.mean = ~ t.test(.x, na.rm = T)))$estimate,              
p.value = ~ t.test(.x, na.rm = T)))$p.value)),.groups = "drop")
```

Comment: Hope here above there's enough to make you a solution...even different from mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of a possible workaround (that may or may not help) by using `across()` "manually", without applying functions one column at a time. The resulting output is a `data.frame` with list columns that are deeply nested, so `unnest()` will come in handy. I also used `possibly()` to address the case when two columns are not present, remember that `across()` can match any number of columns and `t.test()` needs `x` and `y` arguments.

Code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <-
  df %>%
  group_by(tests0, GROUP) %>%
  summarize(
    all = list(across(starts_with("score")) %>%
      {
        tibble(
          ttest   = data.frame(possibly(~ reduce(., ~ t.test(.x, .y, paired = TRUE))[c("estimate", 'p.value')], NA)(.)),
          means   = data.frame(map(., ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% set_names(., str_replace(names(.), "\\D+", "mean"))),
          stderrs = data.frame(map(., ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% set_names(., str_replace(names(.), "\\D+", "stederr")))
        )
      })
  )
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'tests0'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.


data %>%
  unnest(all) %>%
  unnest(-c("tests0", "GROUP"))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 8
#> # Groups:   tests0 [1]
#>   tests0     GROUP    estimate p.value mean0 mean7 stederr0 stederr7
#>   <fct>      <fct>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 ADAS_CogT0 CONTROL     -1.24 0.00471  12.5  13.5     3.72     4.81
#> 2 ADAS_CogT0 TRAINING     1.40 0.00295  14.0  12.6     4.55     4.15
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It's probably the answer I were looking for....it just need to be completed with p.value column

Answer (score 2):

You can use the argument `.names` in `across()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
out %>%
  group_by(tests0, GROUP) %>%
  summarize(across(c(score0, score7), sd, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "sd_{.col}"), 
            across(c(score0, score7), mean, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "mean_{.col}"), 
            diff.std.mean = t.test(score0, score7, paired = T)$estimate, 
            p.value = t.test(score0, score7, paired = T)$p.value) %>%
  ungroup()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'tests0'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 8
#>   tests0 GROUP sd_score0 sd_score7 mean_score0 mean_score7 diff.std.mean p.value
#>   <fct>  <fct>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 ADAS_~ CONT~      3.72      4.81        12.5        13.5         -1.24 0.00471
#> 2 ADAS_~ TRAI~      4.55      4.15        14.0        12.6          1.40 0.00295
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**EDIT**

If you prefer a list it would be easier to determine the separate parts and then bind them together:

```r
library(data.table)
by <- c("tests0", "GROUP")
out_dt <- data.table::data.table(out)
means <- out_dt[, sapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))), 
                by = by, .SDcols = patterns("^score")]
sds <- out_dt[, sapply(.SD, function(x) list(sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))), 
                by = by, .SDcols = patterns("^score")]
t_est <- out_dt[, .(diff.std.mean = t.test(score0, score7, paired = T)$estimate), by = by]
tpvalue <- out_dt[, .(p.value = t.test(score0, score7, paired = T)$p.value), by = by] 
list(means = means, sds = sds, diff.std.mean = t_est, p.value = tpvalue)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I've tried doing this attempt. `out %>% 
  group_by(across(all_of(by))) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with('score'),             
           list(
           mean = ~ mean(.x,na.rm = T),
           stderr = ~ std.error(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
           diff.std.mean = ~ t.test(.x, get(str_replace(cur_column(), "score", "score7")))$estimate,
             p.value = ~ t.test(.x, get(str_replace(cur_column(), "score0", "score7")))$p.value
           )
    ),
    .groups = "drop")`

Comment: Uisng a list out of brackets. Do you think it is possible to odo the same?

Comment: actually if have a look at my comment you could see that there is that `list()` function I would like to manipulate, particularly the .x indexes within

Comment: I updated my answer, it now returns a list

Comment: Look, I really thank you, your answers are pretty instrctive, but maybe I was not clear so far. The thing I'm trying to do is manipute properly the code within `list()` argument (you could see better maybe now, below the high post), because if you try to run it turns back some redundant data. That is just what I need, it is just to be clearer. You've push forward your editings, so I do not want to force you too much. Thus, I thank you. It is always instructive.

Comment: I don’t get what you are trying to achieve. Please update your question with the right input and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach you may want to consider.  First I took your code and cut and pasted it into a function.  Abstracting the column names and removing the dependency on the plotrix package for calculating the standard error are the only changes.

```
g <- function (df)
{
  nms <- c(names(df)[1:2],
           paste0('mean',   sub(".*[a-z]","",names(df)[3])),
           paste0('stderr', sub(".*[a-z]","",names(df)[3])),
           paste0('mean',   sub(".*[a-z]","",names(df)[4])),
           paste0('stderr', sub(".*[a-z]","",names(df)[4])),
           'diff.std.mean', 'p.value')
  
  z <- df %>% group_by(df[,1:2]) %>%
    summarize(
    x1 = mean(pull(df[,3]), na.rm = T),
    x2 = sd(pull(df[,3]), na.rm=T) / sqrt(sum(!is.na(pull(df[,3])))),
    x3 = mean(pull(df[,4]), na.rm = T),
    x4 = sd(pull(df[,4]), na.rm=T) / sqrt(sum(!is.na(pull(df[,4])))),
    x5 = t.test(pull(df[,3]), pull(df[,4]), paired = T)$estimate, 
    x6 = t.test(pull(df[,3]), pull(df[,4]), paired = T)$p.value)
    colnames(z) <- nms
    return(z)
}
```

Then, because the test data only had one level of a factor and insufficient sample size for the plotrix::std.error function that you used, I introduced variation in the 'test0' factor, doubled the sample size, and dropped the unused levels because they would cause iterations on empty frames.  In addition I added a score8 to show how you could run on other variables.

```
s <- t %>% mutate(tests0 = case_when(Education <= 8 ~ 'ADAS_CogTO', T ~ 'PVF_T0'),
                  score8 = score0 + score7)
q <- rbind(s, s)  
fct_drop(q$tests0)
```

Then I split the frame by the factor levels, applied the function to each of the splits, then remerged the data back together inside a function that allows you to manipulate the score and group variables.  I assumed 2 each, which is safe with the score variables since your are doing a paired t-test, and it is easily extendible with the group variables (if you simply move the score variables to positions 1 and 2, and use all remaining variables passed to the function as group variables).

```
h <- function(df, group_vars, score_vars)
{
  z <- df %>% select(group_vars, score_vars) 
  z <- z  %>% group_by(z[,1:2]) %>%
              group_map( ~ g(.x), .keep = T) %>%
              bind_rows()
}
```

Note that if you desire to apply this to other data, you only need to change the columns passed to the group and score variables.  Should be fairly easy to alter that if you want to as well, just thought this was a good framework for what you seem to be trying to do.  Think about how you handle the case where test0 is null and test7 is non-null (or vice-versa) since these observations are included in come of your summary statistics, but necessarily excluded from the t-test.  Good luck.

```
x <- h(q, c("tests0", "GROUP"), c("score0", "score7")) %>%
 group_by(tests0) %>%
 pivot_wider(id_cols     = tests0,
             names_from  = GROUP,
             values_from = c("mean0","stderr0","mean7","stderr7",
                             'diff.std.mean', 'p.value'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Btw I'm looking to manipulate the code in order to obatin the same results with that list() function

Comment: It's a cool function really, but actually the reksults I'm looking for include the manipulation of the .x indexes within the list() function

Comment: Although I don't quite get what you are attempting to say by "include the manipulation of the .x indexes within the list() function" I generalized the names/inputs and made the output names conditional on the input names (which seems to be what you want).

Comment: Do you seeel the last code? The one below the dataset I provided...if you try to run it as it is, it gets back some redundant values, since values under column MEAN, are the same under column DIFF.STD.MEAN....this implies that `.x` in `t.test()` function should be rewritten in a proper way to perform the `t.test()`....this is just to be clearer....to want to force anyone to edit solution persistently

Comment: That code doesn't execute, so I really can't tell from that.  You are passing in a list?vector? named  **by** that I can not see.  I suspect you are attempting to run t-tests with every combination of scores, but you also may be attempting to run t-tests with various combinations of grouping variables across all scores.

Comment: Summarize across only operates on one column at at time as far as I know.  That is why the .x column can not perform the t-test.  That is why I pulled out the across and instead iterated through the by groups.  I added a pivot_wider following that so you can see both you get the data in the expected format (from other question), and the t-test is performed on the column difference.  I still think you may have an issue in including records with a score0 in the mean calculation, but not in the t-test due to a missing score7.  Cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239639/discussion-between-jim-and-maly-statystyczny).

Comment: I just texted you there

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a function called `std.error` so I've used `sd`, but of course you can change it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

out %>% 
  group_by(tests0, GROUP) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(c(score0, score7), list(mean = mean, stderr = sd), na.rm = TRUE,
           .names = '{.fn}{parse_number(.col)}'),
    with(t.test(score0, score7, paired = T),
         tibble(diff.std.mean = estimate,
                p.value)))
# # A tibble: 2 × 8
#   tests0     GROUP    mean0 stderr0 mean7 stderr7 diff.std.mean p.value
#   <fct>      <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 ADAS_CogT0 CONTROL   12.5    3.72  13.5    4.81         -1.24 0.00471
# 2 ADAS_CogT0 TRAINING  14.0    4.55  12.6    4.15          1.40 0.00295
```

In reality I would just put the above code in a function that takes an `x` and `y` argument and then run `fun(df, x = score0, y = score7)`. But, just for fun, if you must use `.x` and `.y`, here's one way (although imo it would be a little silly to do this)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(tests0, GROUP) %>% 
  select(starts_with('score')) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(everything(), list(mean = mean, stderr = sd), na.rm = TRUE,
           .names = '{.fn}{parse_number(.col)}'),
    across(everything(), list(list)) %>% 
      pmap_dfr(~ t.test(.x, .y, paired = TRUE)[c('estimate', 'p.value')]) %>% 
      transmute(diff.std.mean = estimate, p.value))

# # A tibble: 2 × 8
# # Groups:   tests0 [1]
#   tests0     GROUP    mean0 stderr0 mean7 stderr7 diff.std.mean p.value
#   <fct>      <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 ADAS_CogT0 CONTROL   12.5    3.72  13.5    4.81         -1.24 0.00471
# 2 ADAS_CogT0 TRAINING  14.0    4.55  12.6    4.15          1.40 0.00295
```

Comment: Hi, nice  code, by the what the fact to split mean and sd from t.test is due to the fact that is easier to script the code? Can you try the solution with the solution I posted down the dataset? How should script .x for t.test function?

Comment: I split it because `across` applies functions to one column at a time. For the `t.test`, you need two columns.

Comment: What do you mean exaclty? Do you refer to the code below the dataset? Do you think that using always that .x index is possible to compute the t.test()?

Comment: The t.test function needs two columns. `.x` within `across` refers to a single column. I do not think it is possible.

Comment: Ah ok. That's why by using the .y index I got some errors...That is the way I'm looking for